# Is 'the faint sound of footsteps on the snow' correct?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Is 'the faint sound of footsteps **on** the snow' correct?

Or should it be 'the faint sound of footsteps **in** the snow'?

Comment: "Footsteps in the the snow" sounds better, like "footprints in the sand".

Comment: The faint *crunch* of footsteps in the snow.

Comment: *on the snow* is legitimate and can work. *on* suggests moving "over the snow" quickly and leaving little trace, including that of sound.

Comment: If you're walking on a sidewalk and it just started snowing, your footsteps are landing *on* the snow, which won't be more than an inch deep. If you're walking through the woods after an overnight snowstorm and there's a foot of snow on the ground, then *in* the snow makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, crunch of footsteps in the snow [the foot is going into the snow] or on the snow [the snow is packed down and the foot doesn't go down to the sidewalk, street or ground].

Comment: Not all snow crunches, some squeaks.

Comment: Both *on* and *in* work. But they mean different things, and represent different sounds. It's all about the condition of the snow (e.g. packed, icy, fluffy, deep).

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, like the sound of a dentist filling cavities.

Comment: I second @HotLicks 's response. "Crunch" is a very good auditory adjective, and it appeals well to the sense of sound. Edit: just noticed this was quite old.

Answer (score 1):

As often happens, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=footsteps+on+the+snow%2Cfootsteps+in+the+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfootsteps%20on%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfootsteps%20in%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0) can help you out:

[image: Ngrams analysis]

Both prepositions can be used here but **in** is roughly twice as common.

A little bit of logic can also come into this: when you step through snow, your foot sinks slightly, leaving a footprint behind. Due to the fact that your foot in going **in** to the snow and not just staying on the surface, **in** is most appropriate. This difference is starkest with a material that you can step *in* and *on*; concrete. If you step *in* some concrete, then it is likely to be wet, fresh concrete recently laid but if you step *on* some concrete, it is likely to be a paving slab.

Comment: Nevertheless, if the footsteps are *on the snow* it suggests of someone moving quickly "over the snow",  leaving little trace of their movement, a scenario that matches a faint sound. If you can move over the snow  you can move on the snow.  It's up to the author here. One shouldn't be bound or even advised to "go by what the multitude does".

Comment: @Clare Very true, this is in the end just advice, not a definitive solution.

Comment: On the snow suggests the snow is packed down. In the snow does not.

Comment: These Ngrams do not help, as the 'sound of...' determines that the footsteps are not the footprint sense.

Comment: @Lambie - Or the snow could have a thick crust.

Comment: @Jim Yes, that too. Every single option does not always come to mind immediately...